How to run multi-threaded or parallel curl command in loop from bash?
I'm looking to a solution for making curl request automation.
Currently I managed it via loop option and that works fine, but because I didn't know how to implement parallelism and multi-threads, my solution working too slow.
How can I make my current solution multi-threaded and make it faster?
for i in {0000001..0000100}; do
  curl --retry 20  'http://example.com/Services/ServiceWS ' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8' \
  --data-raw 'User'$i'' \
  --insecure \
  --output 'User'$i.output
done

I should send User0000001 in my request so placed zero(0) before numbers.
[** additional question when I execute number generation part directly in bash it's work fine for i in {0000001..0000100}; do echo $i; done and numbers printed starting with 000 but when I saved that script in .sh file and execute that, starting 00 will be ignored and 1 2 3 4 appears as result.]
--retry for managing 5xx error status. it's important to manage statuses and retry on each request to get 200 status code.

Have you considered using GNU Parallel?

You can use $(printf 'User%07d' $i) to get leading zeroes.

Another possible explanation for the disappearing zeros is that you are running an old version of Bash (e.g. the ancient Bash 3.x version that is the default on macOS).  Run echo "$BASH_VERSION" to check your Bash version.  One way to use brace expansion to get the desired list of numbers with Bash 3 is 0000{00{0..9},0{10..99},{100..999}}

I suggest without your loop:
curl --retry 20 'http://example.com/Services/ServiceWS?[0000001-0000100]' \
-H 'Accept: */*' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
-H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8' \
--data-raw 'User#1' \
--insecure \
--output 'User#1.output' --parallel

I assume that the website is not bothered by the fact that a number appears at the end of the URL as a GET parameter.
